# R write fixed width columns to csv (in the plain text file)

Tags: r, csv, fixed-width

I write data frames to csv files using write.csv(). When this is done, the output when viewed in a plain text editor, in particular vi or notepad++, shows no spacing between the column content and the commas, resulting in it being relatively hard to read. For example, the columns are not lined up down the page.

I have negative interest in using excel to view the csv files. I am definitely not looking for a suggestion for a csv viewer. Nor do I want instructions on how to modify the plain text file afterward. Padding needs to be spaces not tabs.

*I am interested in how to get R to line up the columns in the plain text csv file so that they are easier to read using a non specialized plain text editor.*

I could (and might) write my own routine that converts everything to some fixed width string format and print that. But, I would prefer to find that this is an option within write.csv() or similar common output library call.

[I just this moment found out about printf in R, and that might be the best answer to this conundrum].

Comment: Use tabs instead of commas. e.g.  `write.table(iris, "iris.dat", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)`  . In vi the default tab stop is 8 but if you want something else you can use, for example, `:set ts=4`  or `:set ts=10` .

Comment: Alternately write an ordinary csv and then read it into vi and in vi replace the commas with tabs : `:%s/,/\t/g`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck sep=",\t" would be closer to the mark, as I do want a csv, with an emphasis on c, file. But, this would not work as entries wider than the tab would still not line up. I have modified the question to emphasize what I am looking and what not.